# Errors while installing GIT in RAD8.5

Tags: git, rad

I am using RAD8.5.I want to install GIT as it is required for my project. I did following steps

1. Help
2. Install new software
3. I used the below link to install git.
   http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1

But I am getting an error that "Could not find  http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looked in Eclipse Marketplace and this is the URL you should use to install it

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

This is the link you can use to see EGit in Eclipse Marketplace

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider#.VGzpNIWoA6U